# Event Signature in C#

Tags: c#

I having a little but of hard time understanding this line of code below:

```
types(lstTypes[i].AvailableDatatype);
```

I'm not sure what is the purpose of AvailableDatatype.

Here the full code ...

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<DotNet> lstTypes = new List<DotNet>();
            DotNet bltypes = new DotNet();
            bltypes.AvailableDatatype = "bool";
            lstTypes.Add(bltypes);    

            DotNet strTypes = new DotNet();
            strTypes.AvailableDatatype = "string";
            lstTypes.Add(strTypes);

            DotNet intTypes = new DotNet();
            intTypes.AvailableDatatype = "int";
            lstTypes.Add(intTypes);

            DotNet decTypes = new DotNet();
            decTypes.AvailableDatatype = "decimal";
            lstTypes.Add(decTypes);    

            types += x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                Console.ReadLine();
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= lstTypes.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                types(lstTypes[i].AvailableDatatype);
            }    
        }

        static event Action<string> types;    
    }    

    public class DotNet
    {
        public string AvailableDatatype { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: @LarsTech good point, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `types` event represent a method which takes a `string` as its sole argument.

`AvailableDatatype` is a `string` type, so it can be used as `types`'s argument.

What this code is doing is calling every delegated method of the event `types` for each element of the `lstTypes` list by using these elements' `AvailableDatatype` as the argument of these methods.